# CMD - Saltar login al conectar por FTP

Tags: cmd, batch, ftp

Tengo el siguiente script.bat que me pide que introduzca el usuario y la contraseña a pesar de haberla especificado en el código. ¿Qué he hecho mal? Yo quiero que se identifique automáticamente, con solo ejecutar el bat tiene que hacerse todo.

```
ftp ftp.web.net
usuario
password
cd /public_html/MARKETING/blah
binary
mput "C:\Users\blah\datos.xlsx" /y
bye
```

Answer (score 0):

En el `Ftp` de Windows/dos la forma de ejecutar una serie de instrucciones es indicando con el parámetro `-s` el nombre del `script` que contiene los comando a ejecutar. Una forma de implementar todo de forma automática en un BAT es generar de forma dinámica este `script`. Por ejemplo así:

```
@echo off

::****** Configuración ***************
::************************************
Set FTPSERVER=ftp.dlptest.com
Set USER=dlpuser@dlptest.com
Set PASS=eiTqR7EMZD5zy7M
::************************************


set script=%TEMP%\ftp-script.txt

echo Creamos un Script FTP en: %script% ...

::****** Conexión inicial ************
echo user %USER% %PASS%> %script%
::************************************

::****** Comando ftp a ejecutar ******
echo remotehelp >> %script%
echo bye >> %script%
::************************************

echo Nos conectamos al ftp y corremos el script...

ftp -n -s:%script% %FTPSERVER%

del %script%
```

Comment: Me da error de login: 530 Login incorrect. Error al iniciar la sesión. Los acabo de probar en mi cliente filezilla y las credenciales están bien, no hay espacios.

Comment: @EnergyPanel, revisa el archivo Script generado (`%script%`) para ver si efectivamente los datos de login son los que corresponden, particularmente la password.

Comment: @EnergyPanel, hice unos cambios para que se enviará correctamente la password, probado con un sitio público que pide usuario y contraseña. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Me autocontesto con una solución:

```
    @echo off
    echo user adminz> ftpcmd.dat
    echo passxxxx>> ftpcmd.dat
    echo cd "/public_html/">> ftpcmd.dat
    echo put "C:\Users\doc.xlsx">> ftpcmd.dat
    echo quit>> ftpcmd.dat
    ftp -n -s:ftpcmd.dat ftp.web---.net
    del ftpcmd.dat

    timeout /t 10
```

Supongo que esto es otro problema diferente ya.